# Cannot read ZF correctly?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I'm finding myself unable to read the zero flag (ZF) bit correctly. I'm quite confused, because this approach appears to work fine for other flags such as the carry flag (CF) or overflow flag (OF). My strategy is to push the `EFLAGS` register onto the stack with the instruction `pushf`, then select the ZF bit with a bitwise AND.

In the code below, I set EAX to 0xFFFFFFFE, so after incrementing once it should be 0xFFFFFFFF and ZF should be zero. After incrementing it twice then EAX should be 0x0 and ZF should be one, if my understanding is correct. However, my program outputs:

```
Value of Zero Flag: 0
Value of Zero Flag: 0
```

Where I expect it to output:

```
Value of Zero Flag: 0
Value of Zero Flag: 64
```

My code is this:

```
.text
.global main

main:

    movl    $0xfffffffe, %eax

    addl    $1, %eax

    pushf
    pop     %ebx
    andl    $0x40, %ebx
    pushl   %ebx
    pushl   $strzf
    pushl   $string
    call    printf
    pop     %ebx
    pop     %ebx
    pop     %ebx


    addl    $1, %eax

    pushf
    pop     %ebx
    andl    $0x40, %ebx
    pushl   %ebx
    pushl   $strzf
    pushl   $string
    call    printf
    pop     %ebx
    pop     %ebx
    pop     %ebx

    leave
    ret

.section        .rodata
    string:
        .string "Value of %s: %d\n"
    strzf:
        .string "ZF"
```

Comment: Check the register values with gdb and determine what actually causes the problem.

Comment: Great suggestion as always! The call to printf was mangling eax

Comment: `printf` clobbers your `eax`, you need to save that too. As Downvoter said, use a debugger.